# Hyperledger Fabric. First app. Enrolling the Admin User

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I follow the instructions on the page [Writing Your First Application](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html)

I stuked with the problem on the step [Enrolling the Admin User](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html#enrolling-the-admin-user)

The problem is that eCert and key material does not appear in **hfc-key-store** directory inspite of the fact that all previous steps passed successfully

I just run `node enrollAdmin.js`
And there is nothing but store path:

`Store path:~/fabric-samples/fabcar/hfc-key-store`

What I'm doing wrong or it's a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This was my fault.

[Node.js Runtime and NPM](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html#node-js-runtime-and-npm) section says that certain Node.js version is required - 6.9.*. I used 4.2. After installing Node.js of version 6.9.1 everything works purfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ROOTDIR for a folder named .hfc-key-store.
Delete it.
Then try again.

I had a similar problem. The script would not create the .hfc-key-store, as it already existed from a previous created network.